# ¿Como pasar un usuario con Mockito para los test del controlador?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, mockito

tengo un pequeño problema y es que no se como pasar un usuario al controlador, el cual se obtiene a partir de otro usuario.

El método del controlador que estoy testeando te muestra una sugerencia de amistad:

```
@GetMapping("/suggestion")
public final String showSuggestions(HttpServletRequest request, final ModelMap model)
        throws SuggestionNotFoundException {
    User user;
    User userSuggested;
    HttpSession misession;
    List<Image> userImages;
    ImageOutputData defaultOutput;

    misession = request.getSession(false);

    if (misession == null) {
        return ErrorViewConstants.NOT_LOGIN;
    }
    user = (User) misession.getAttribute(UserViewConstants.BEAN_USER_LOGGED);

    //ERROR
    userSuggested = getFriendshipService().userSugestion(user);

    // lista de imagenes del usuario
    userImages = getImageService().getAllUserImages(userSuggested.getId());

    // imagen por defecto
    defaultOutput = new ImageOutputData();

    // si no hay elementos, mostramos imagen por defecto
    if (userImages.isEmpty()) {
        defaultOutput.setId(-1);
        defaultOutput.setPath(UtilConstants.DEFAULT_IMAGE);
        defaultOutput.setNoImage(true);
        defaultOutput.setUserAge(userSuggested.userAge());
        defaultOutput.setUserCity(userSuggested.getCity());
        defaultOutput.setUserDescription(userSuggested.getDescription());
        defaultOutput.setUserSex(userSuggested.getSex().toString());
    } else {
        Image defaultImage = userImages.remove(0);

        defaultOutput.setPath(defaultImage.getPath());
        defaultOutput.setId(defaultImage.getId());
        defaultOutput.setUserAge(defaultImage.getUser().userAge());
        defaultOutput.setUserCity(defaultImage.getUser().getCity());
        defaultOutput.setUserDescription(defaultImage.getUser().getDescription());
        defaultOutput.setNoImage(false);
        defaultOutput.setUserSex(defaultImage.getUser().getSex().toString());
    }

    // lista de fotos obtenidas
    UserSuggestionOutputForm suggestion = new UserSuggestionOutputForm();

    suggestion.setId(userSuggested.getId());
    suggestion.setUserAge(userSuggested.userAge());
    suggestion.setUserCity(userSuggested.getCity());
    suggestion.setUserSex(userSuggested.getSex().toString());
    suggestion.setDescription(userSuggested.getDescription());
    suggestion.setUsername(userSuggested.getUsername());
    suggestion.setAverageRating(getUserService().getAverageRating(userSuggested.getId()));

    // foto que mostramos por defecto
    model.put(UserViewConstants.DEFAULT_IMAGE, defaultOutput);
    model.put(ImageViewConstants.IMAGES_CAROUSEL, ControllerMethods.outputList(userImages));
    model.put(UserViewConstants.BEAN_USER_SUGGESTED, suggestion);
    model.put(UserViewConstants.BEAN_USER_LOGGED, user);

    return FriendshipViewConstants.SUGGESTION;
}
```

Donde pone la etiqueta //ERROR es donde surge el problema, ya que paso un mock de user y por lo tanto userSuggested es null. Entonces, quiero pasar por el test del controlador userSuggested para que no me lanze la excepcion y poder probar el método.

Adjunto el código del test del controlador:

```
@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
public class TestSuggestionFriendshipController {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    FriendshipService service;

    public TestSuggestionFriendshipController() {
        super();
    }

    @BeforeEach
    public final void setUpMockContext() throws InstanceNotFoundException {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(showSuggestionsController())
            .alwaysExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk()).build();
    }

    @Test
    public final void testShowSuggestion() throws Exception {

        mockMvc.perform(getSuggestionsViewRequest());
    }

    private final FriendshipSuggestionController showSuggestionsController() throws InstanceNotFoundException {

        final ImageService imageService;
        final UserService userService;

        this.service = Mockito.mock(FriendshipService.class);
        imageService = Mockito.mock(ImageService.class);
        userService = Mockito.mock(UserService.class);

        return new FriendshipSuggestionController(service, imageService, userService);
    }

    private final RequestBuilder getSuggestionsViewRequest() throws SuggestionNotFoundException {
        User user = new User();
        User userSuggested = new User();

        this.service = Mockito.mock(FriendshipService.class);

        user.setId(1);
        userSuggested.setId(2);

          Mockito.when(service.userSugestion(user)).thenReturn(userSuggested);

        return MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(UrlFriendshipConfig.SUGGESTIONS).sessionAttr("userLogged", user);

    }
}
```

Al ejecutar los test me está lanzando la siguiente error : NullPointerException

Un saludo y muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)

Comment: pon el código de  `getFriendshipService()`, seguramente allí está el problema

Answer (score 0):

Tienes lo siguiente en tu test:

```
service = Mockito.mock(FriendshipService.class);
```

El problema es que no le estás añadiendo ningún comportamiento más a ese mock, pero podrías hacer algo como:

```
when(service.userSugestion(ArgumentMatchers.any()).thenReturn(new User(...));
```

De este modo no tendrás ese NPE, devolverás un nuevo usuario (que puedes crear como quieras, yo he puesto simplemente una llamada al constructor como ejemplo)

Comment: Hola, en el método getSuggestionsViewRequest() de la clase TestSuggestionFriendshipController puedes ver que ya hago la parte del when(...).thenReturn(...). Sigo teniendo el mismo problema y es que la llamada al método del servicio me sigue devolviendo null. Un saludo y muchas gracias

Comment: Tienes dos variables locales en tu código llamadas service, pero la que inyectas en el controller no es a la que has añadido el comportamiento

Comment: Hola, ya modifiqué lo que me comentaste como puedes ver ahora arriba en el código, pero me sigue lanzando la excepción. Un saludo